# How many combinations of md5sums can be computed from a call to random() in PostgreSQL?

Tags: random, md5, rainbow-table, postgresql

## Problem space

I'm way out of my pay grade, I'm trying to figure out

- **How much randomness does a call to random() actually provide in PostgreSQL?**

  ```
  SELECT random();
  ```
- **Whether or not you can reasonably guess that much randomness?**

## What I know

1. I know it's not as random as people want it to be, it's just inefficient. Having concluded long ago that `md5()` is a waste of time, I can just compare the sizes.

   ```
   --produces "8" (in bytes)
   SELECT pg_column_size(random());

   --produces "36" (in bytes)
   SELECT pg_column_size(md5(random()::text));
   ```

   That's a lot of wasted space. I know we can store [md5() in UUID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/2639) which will take 16 bytes. But, that's still 8 bytes of waste space from our original 8 byte random().
2. I know PostgreSQL currently generates [random numbers like this](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/utils/adt/float.c#L2416),

   ```
   result = (double) random() / ((double) MAX_RANDOM_VALUE + 1);

   PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(result);
   ```

   And, I know that `PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(result)` is a macro that calls [`Float8GetDatum(result)`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/include/postgres.h#L740).
3. The [docs on `random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) say this,

   > **The characteristics of the values returned by random() depend on the system implementation.** It is not suitable for cryptographic applications; see pgcrypto module for an alternative.
4. I believe that 8 byte float, is an Standard 754 IEEE float under the hood, also from the docs.

   > The data types real and double precision are inexact, variable-precision numeric types. In practice, these types are usually implementations of **IEEE Standard 754 for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (single and double precision, respectively), to the extent that the underlying processor, operating system, and compiler support it.**
5. I know that the full precision of IEEE 754 supports the following states that our `random()` **does not support.**

   1. Negative numbers
   2. Not-a-number
   3. Infinity
   4. Negative Infinity
6. I know that [IEEE reserves 11 bits for the exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), and we're guaranteed to have that in a position that yields numbers in the range of `(0,1)`. [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html),

   > random value in the range `0.0 <= x < 1.0`.
7. Not sure how accurate (I would prefer this checked with the above information), but for an [8-byte double the docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

   > variable-precision, inexact  15 decimal digits precision

With all of that is anyone fluent enough in 754, and C to actually tell me how random a call to `random()` really is.

## Why I am asking

I made a suggestion to generate session keys not using `md5(random()::text)` stored in text, but instead to use `pgcrypto`'s `gen_random_uuid()` now I'm wondering how much it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random() can have at most 64 bits of significance, since it's a double precision float. That assumes perfect random number generation and all that.

We only produce a random significand, the sign and exponent is fixed. The fractional part of the significand is 52 bits.

So ... about 2^52 possible values.

It looks like you're thinking of the rainbow table as a mapping of the md5 of the text representation of a double precision float back to the original float. Assuming you're using `extra_float_digits = 3`, that'd take up roughly `128 * 2^52` bytes, so a couple of exabytes, in exchange for reducing your search space from 2^128 to 2^52. Not that exciting, really.

I'd still want a good reason not to just use a `uuid-ossp`'s `uuid_generate_v4()`. How big can your session tables really be? [You know PostgreSQL has *huge* per-row overheads right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13570613/398670)?

---

Separately, you don't have to use `uuid` to store an `md5`, or format it as text. You can also use `bytea`. It'll be packed into a short-varlena Datum which has a 1-byte length so it'll take up 17 bytes. (See: `VARSIZE_ANY` in `src/include/postgres.h`, and `src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c`).